# A way to identify punctuation in hebrew? C#

Tags: c#, punctuation

lately a thought came accross my mind on whether or not its possible to identify punctuation of a word in hebrew, using C#. 
There are a few punctuation mark in the hebrew language, such as:

```
יוּעָדוּ
```

Of course that usually we dont punctuate words, so it should appear like:

```
יועדו
```

Is there a way to identify the punctuation of a word such as this using C#?

Comment: Are you looking for anything more than what string compare and matching can achieve?

Comment: You can use a regex and search for the punctuation characters, but I'm sure you already knew that. What have you tried that doesn't work?

Comment: @ryadavilli  - What I'm looking for is a word which can identify the punctuation of a word. For example, the word I wrote in my post, I would like the C# program to identify the punctuated words and the punctuation itself. I hope you understand my question better now.

Comment: @lc. I have done some reading about regex and it wasnt what I needed. I haven't tried anything yet, all I did was just reading and thinking how to answer my question, which eventually led me here.

Comment: Just look up the Unicode category of the character.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, the sequences parse as follows:

```
>>> a = unicode('יוּעָדוּ', 'utf-8')
>>> b = unicode('יועדו', 'utf-8')
>>> a
u'\u05d9\u05d5\u05bc\u05e2\u05b8\u05d3\u05d5\u05bc'
>>> b
u'\u05d9\u05d5      \u05e2      \u05d3\u05d5'
```

(I've added spaces to make things clearer.)

You can see the punctuation tokens standing out quite clearly. A C# regex that looks for these is probably the direction you want to go.